# Does $S_1\subseteq \overline{S}_2-S_2$ $\implies$ $\dim S_1<\dim S_2$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> **Question:** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $S_1,S_2\subseteq M$ two locally-closed submanifolds (i.e. they are open in their closure). If
>   $$S_1\subseteq\overline{S}_2-S_2,$$
>   is it true that
>   $$\dim S_1<\dim S_2?$$

I believe it is true since it seems that it is used implicitly in [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2944350?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper (the sentence between Definitions 1.5 and 1.6). But I couldn't find a way to prove it rigourously.

Comment: Hint: The condition on $S_1$ and $S_2$ says that $S_1$ is contained in the boundary of $S_2$. Are you familiar with the boundary operator? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

Comment: @JustinBenfield I am familiar with the notion of topological boundary. I also know that the manifold boundary of a manifold is a manifold of $1$ dimension lower. But I don't see the relation between these two concepts here.

Comment: This explains the relationship a bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary

Comment: @JustinBenfield It doesn't; those are really two different concepts. If otherwise, please explain.

Comment: The notion of the boundary of a (topological) manifold with boundary coincides with the topological notion (the latter is more general). This is because the manifold $M$ is also a topological space, its topology being defined from the requirement on the charts and transition functions where said charts overlap that the relevant maps be (local) homeomorphisms. For any topological space, then entire space is both an open and closed set. In the case of manifold with boundary, (cont.)

Comment: The interior is the open subset formed by all the points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to the ball instead of a *half* ball (as mentioned in article on manifold). It's complement is the boundary of the manifold (all the points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to the half ball), and hence is also closed. Using the fact you know that boundary of manifold has dimension 1 less, and the fact that $S_1$ is a subset of that boundary, you can conclude that $\dim S_1\leq\dim\partial\overline{S}_2$ (and the latter is strictly less than $\dim S_2$).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Careful. The topological boundary of a topological space depends on an embedding. Given a manifold $M$ alone, its topological boundary is not well-defined, unless you consider $M$ sitting in itself, where in this case the boundary is empty. Your first sentence that manifold boundary coincide with topological boundary is plain wrong. For example, think of a 2-dimensional disk in $\Bbb R^3$. Its topological boundary is the disk itself, while its manifold boundary is a circle.

Comment: @Spenser: Good catch, rather, what's important is the set of points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to the ball (rather than half ball). That set, by virtue of being open is equal to its interior. That set's boundary as a subset of the given manifold with boundary is the boundary we are interested in.

Comment: @JustinBenfield How do you know that $\overline{S}_2$ is a manifold with boundary?